# Code gives segmentation faults or never completes its run

Tags: c, linked-list, segmentation-fault

My code is for removing a value, `target` from a linked list `L`. For some reason I cannot find, it either causes a segmentation fault or never runs through the second print statement. It also should return 0 if the numbers are removed and 1 if they  aren't.

```
unsigned int removeNumber(LL_t * L, int target)

{
    int ret = 0;
    node_t * current = L->head;
    node_t * previous = NULL;
    node_t * tmp = current;

    for(current = L->head; current != NULL; previous = current, current->next)
    {
        if ((current->data == target) && (previous != NULL))
        {
            free(current);
            current = current->next;
            previous = current;
            ret += 1;
        }
        else if ((current->data == target) && (previous == NULL)){
            L->head = current->next;
        }
    }
    if (ret > 0)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Please include the complete program that exhibits the problem.  Instructions are here [mcve]

Comment: what do you think you are doing here `free(current); current = current->next;`

Comment: A few more errors:  You never advance `current` to `current->next`, so this doesn't actually walk the list.  Your remove-from-head-of-list code doesn't increment `ret`, and it leaks memory by never calling `free`

Comment: Questions about your question:  There is no print statement in the code you posted, so what were you expecting to see printed?  Also, are you trying to remove _all_ nodes with the `target` data?  If so, I would expect the return value to be the number of nodes removed (you're counting them, after all); using a `0` to indicate a non-zero number of nodes removed is... weird.

Comment: Normally, in implementation like yours removal of `current` node from a list involves correcting `previous->next` link. I don't see it anywhere in your code.

Answer (score -1):

Your code have some errors, Use this code instead.

```
unsigned int removeNumber(LL_t * L, int target)

{
    int ret = 0;
    node_t * current = L->head;
    node_t * previous = NULL;
    node_t * tmp = current;

if(current->data==target)
{
 L->head=current->next;
  free(current);
  ret++;
}

else
{

    for(current = L->head; current->next != NULL; current= current->next)
    {
        if ((current->next->data == target) )
        {
            free(current);
            previous = current->next;
            current->next= previous->next;
            free(previous);
           ret++;
        }

    }

}
   if (ret > 0)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Please read "[answer]".  On Stack Overflow, code-only answers are generally considered unhelpful, because they don't explain why the old code didn't work and the new code works (assuming it does work...).  At the very least, mark and explain your changes by adding comments to the code block.

Comment: Your code does not compile.  `head` is undefined (I think you meant `L->head`).  Also, if the `target` appears in the first node, your function skips past all the `return` statements, returning some garbage value.  You `free` the memory pointed to by `current` and then attempt to both read from and write to it.  Finally, the original function (attempts to) remove _all_ nodes containing the `target` value; since @Jimotheyturner has not replied to questions about this, we can only guess if that was the intent --- there's not enough information here to answer the question.

Comment: thanks for the correction. Ya I also assumed that all the nodes with target value need to be removed. Also his code had a lots of problems, thatswhy i couldnt point them line by line